# Replace date format in Notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have dates as `MonthYear`, `Month-Year` (ex: May16, Jul-21) but I need them to be in `dd.mm.yyyy` format.

For example:
`Aug20`, needs to become `01.08.2020`
`May-19`, needs to become `01.05.2019`
`Jul18`, needs to become `01.07.2018`
`Nov-17`, needs to become `01.11.2017`

Thank you.

Comment: This not a job for Npp, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @Toto Isn't it possible with something like this `((Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))-(([0-4])\d|[5-9]\d))`

Comment: Yes, it can be done with conditional replacement but it is unreadable and unmaintainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you really want to do it in a single replacement**.

You have to use conditional replacements but it is unreadable and unmaintainable !

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))-?(\d\d)`
- Replace with: `01(?1.01.)(?2.02.)(?3.03.)(?4.04.)(?5.05.)(?6.06.)(?7.07.)(?8.08.)(?9.09.)(?10.10.)(?11.11.)(?12.12)20$13`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
(Jan)           # group 1, Jan
|               # OR
(Feb)           # group 2, Feb
|               # OR
(Mar)           etc.    
|
(Dec)           # group 12 Dec
)               # end group
-?              # optional hyphen
(\d\d)          # group 13, 2 digits
```

**Replacement:**

```
01              
(?1.01.)        # if group 1 exists, print .01.
(?2.02.)        # if group 2 exists, print .02.
etc.
(?12.12)        # if group 12 exists, print .12.
20              # 20
$13             # content of group 13, the 2 digit year
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with one regex is horribly complex and is not worth the effort
(unless one takes it as a challenge).

You would need to write 12 replacements for each month. For example:

Find what : `Aug-?(\d\d)`
Replace with : `01.08.20\1`
Tick "Regular expression" and untick ". matches newline".

Where `-?` means the character `-` is optional.

[image]